# A post on a external jquery file doesn't work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

Im using ASP.NET MVC5 with Jquery 3.3.1, before, i have the post on the same page of the view inside of an script tag and it works perfectly. But i heard is better have your functions in a external jsfile.

the post is for get a simple array of data and fill a datatable.

the others functions on my jsfile are working good, but my post is returning me a 404 not found, i put a breakpoint on my JsonAction but the post dont even call it.

Sorry for my bad English

This is my POST function:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetCardsData","Card")';

$.post(url).done(function (data) {
    var request = JSON.parse(data);

    var i = 0;
    var exist = false;


    request.filter(function (el) {

        el.filter(function (ul) {

            array[i] = ul;


            i++;


        })

    });
```

My JsonAction:

```
 public JsonResult GetCardsData(string CardNumber) {
        if (CardNumber == null) {
                            CardNumber = "";
        }
        int? Reference_ID = User.Reference_ID;
        Card c = CardRepo.GetCard(Company.Company_ID, CardNumber);

        new AdmSql();
        var cardListq = @"SELECT * FROM  [DEF].[GetCardsData] ({0}, 3)";
        var cardList = DEFRepo.ParseList(DaSql.Query(cardListq, Reference_ID));
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cardList);


        return Json(data);
    }
```

[this is the error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epdJ3.png)

Comment: When you put the JS in an external file the Razor call to `@Url.Action()` will not be executed and will remain as plain text. You'll need to keep that part in the main Razor view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that '**@Url.Action**' will not work in external **JS Files**. It can be called from .cshtml or .vbhtml  files only.

But if you still want to make a call from external JS File then you should simply pass `'/Card/GetCardsData'` in url.

Comment: @JuniorLaucel - Please Upvote the answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your `var url = '@Url.Action("GetCardsData","Card")';` code is in .js file. It should not be there, since Razor cannot detect it there, so your Url finally looks as is, so 404 (Not Found) because there is no `@Url.Action("GetCardsData","Card")`, but rather there is `/Card/GetCardsData`. Therefore, put this line inside of your `.cshtml` page like so:

```
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetCardsData","Card")';
</script>
```

Now, your url will be correct.